# Convert float number from nonuniform ranges

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have this, relatively easy, problem and wondering if the solution for it already exists.

I have to convert a value from one range to another. If there was just one range, like this:

```
 {-30.0, 30.0} -> {25.0, 50.0}
```

that would have been easy.
But I have a set of ranges:

```
 {-30.0, -20.0} -> {25.0, 30.0}
 {-20.0,   0.0} -> {30.0, 40.0}
 {  0.0,  30.0} -> {40.0, 50.0}
```

One solution is to do a linear search on each access.
Another solution is to make the ranges to have equivalent length so that the input value could be directly mapped.

Does anyone know a better than linear search solution? Or if a container that performs this kind of conversion already exist?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Can ranges overlap?

Comment: @user1034749 No, they don't overlap.

Comment: @user1034749: a correction - the ranges in input set or output set don't overlap. But, unfortunately, the ranges in input and output do. I.e. {-30.0, -20.0} translates into {-25.0, -20.0}.

Comment: My solution depend only on input "overlaping", output and input relations not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an elaboration on the solution presented by @[user1034749](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034749/user1034749). It uses an [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) with a class that contains two pairs of values.

```
template<class SRC, class DST>
class Range {
 public:
  std::pair<SRC, SRC> src_range;
  std::pair<DST, DST> dst_range;

  bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const {
    return (src_range.first < rhs.src_range.first) && (src_range.second < rhs.src_range.second);
  }

  Range(SRC src_first, SRC src_second,
        DST dst_first, DST dst_second)
  : src_range(src_first, src_second),
    dst_range(dst_first, dst_second) {}

  Range()
  : src_range(0, 0),
    dst_range(0, 0) {}

  Range(SRC value)
  : src_range(value, value),
    dst_range(value, value) {}
};

bool mapping_test() {
  // Mapping
  std::set<Range<double,double>>
          z = {{-30.0, -20.0, -10.0, -5.0},
               {-20.0, 0, -5.0, 5.0},
               {0, 10.0, 5.0, 8.0}};

  // Find range that contains this value
  Range<double,double> f{8.0};

  auto d = z.find(f);
  if(d != z.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found {" << (*d).dst_range.first
                           << ","
                           << (*d).dst_range.second
                           << "}\n";
  }

  return true;
}
```

In this case the range for the value in question could be found including source range as well as destination. Lookup in the [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) container is log(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the range can't overlap. (both domain & range)

I suggest sorting the range.
This way, you can query the range using `O(log n)`.

- push the range into array / some std collection
- using sort http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/.
  To compare, use only min or only max value of the input range.
- query a range using min or max (corresponding as above)

### **Alternative approach**

In some input pattern, this approach can be appropriate :-

**Convert this :-**

```
 {-30.0, -20.0} -> {25.0, 30.0}
 {-20.0,   0.0} -> {30.0, 40.0}
 {  0.0,  30.0} -> {40.0, 50.0}
```

into something more *uniform* :-

```
float [] inputRange =  {-30,-20, -10,0 ,10       ,20       ,30};
float [] outputRange = {25 ,30 ,*35*,40,*43.3333*,*43.6667*,50};
//* is a pre-calculated
```

Then you can query using only `O(1)`.

**Disadvantage :-**

- Waste more memory
- The input have to be *snapped* with some not-so-tiny value. (This case = 10)

Answer (score 0):

As @javaLover replies, instead of linear - O(n) operations,
when n - number of ranges, you can find suitable range by O(log n)
operations, for example with `std::map`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Range = std::pair<double, double>;
    struct RangeLess {
        bool operator()(const Range &a, const Range &b) const {
            return a.first < b.first && a.second < b.second;
        }
    };
    using RangeMap = std::map<Range, Range, RangeLess>;
    const RangeMap ranges_map = {
        {{-30.0, -20.0}, {25.0, 30.0}},
        {{-20.0, 0.0}, {30.0, 40.0}},
        { {1.0, 30.0}, {40.0, 50.0}},
    };
    auto map_point = [&ranges_map](double x) -> double {
        const Range x_range = {x, x};
        auto it = ranges_map.find(x_range);
        if (it == ranges_map.end()) {
            return x;
        } else {
            const Range &in = it->first;
            const Range &out = it->second;

            return (x - in.first) / (in.second - in.first) * (out.second - out.first) + out.first;
        }
    };

    const double patterns[] = {-40, -30, -25, -20, 0.5, 5, 40};
    for (auto &&x : patterns) {
        std::cout << x << " -> " << map_point(x) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: very elegant solution. (1) Can `unordered_map` be used? (2) Sorry I've misunderstood your "non overlap" question. Unfortunately, the   from->to ranges can overlap.